# Label form from an entry in db

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I create a embedded form. How can I label in ItemType.php with the name from the db?

1.) Like:

```
$builder->add('id', 'checkbox', array('label'=> $v->getName(),...
```

2.) By the way symfony2 renders for each ItemType.php a Number 0,1,2. How can I get rid of it?

My action:

```
$task = new UserFriends();

foreach ($fb_friends as $k => $v) {
     $name = $v->getName();
     $friend_id = $v->getFriendId();
     $id = $v->getId();
     $t = new Item();
     $t->name = $name;
     $t->friendId = $friend_id;
     $t->id = $id;
     $task->getId()->add($t);
}
$form = $this->createForm(new CreateRequest(), $task, array());
```

Part of CreateRequest.php-form:

```
$builder->add('id', 'collection', array('type' => new ItemType(),
```

Part of my ItemType.php

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('id', 'checkbox', array('label'=> 'Name', 'required' => false, 'mapped' => false));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Frontend\ChancesBundle\Entity\Item',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'item';
    }
```

And Part of my Item.php-Entity

```
class Item
{
    public $id;

    public $friendId;

    public $name;

    public function getFriendId()
    {
        return $this->friendId;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an entity manager to your form and select whatever you want from the database.

**In your controller (or whereever you are calling the form):**

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$form = $this->createForm(new MyFormType($blabla), $blabla, array('em' => $em));
```

**In your form type:**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $somethingFromDb = $options['em']->findByName('someName');
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{

    $resolver->setRequired(array(
        'em',
    ));

    $resolver->setAllowedTypes(array(
        'em' => 'Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager',
    ));
}
```

Comment: Okay, but how do I get in my case the $em to ItemType()? The ItemType is going to be called so many times, like entries in the db. How can I get then the specific entry from the db that the id matches the name?

Comment: You can pass whatever you want by the $options array. So you can do one select query and then pass the result to ItemType everytime.

Comment: I guess I don't get it. With your solution, I can pass it to the form CreateRequest(). This works! But in the form CreateRequest I am calling the form ItemType(). How can I pass the query to ItemType(), to create the label like I want?

Comment: @Gunnar try this: `array('type' => new ItemType(), 'options' => array('myVar' => 'myValue'));` Then in the `ItemType::buildForm()` check `$options['myVar']`, it possably will be there.